# convert string to datetime in function SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-functions

I have been writing a user-defined function in SQL Server:

It looks like this :

```
CREATE FUNCTION FormatDate(@fromtime nvarchar(50))
RETURNS DATETIME
AS 
BEGIN

    DECLARE @tempfrom datetime
    DECLARE @tempto nvarchar(50)

    set @tempfrom =  Convert(datetime, @fromtime, 100) 
    RETURN @tempfrom

END

select dbo.FormatDate('08/17/2010 4:30')
```

When I try to run this, I get the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '08/17/2010 4:30' to data type int.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why nvarchar? Are you going to have umlauts and yen symbols in your date strings?

Comment: @NullUserException tee hee Stop it, you're making me want to go slack off and visit the chive

Comment: hey i can open the team viewer for you and show it.. it is 100% CODE....

Comment: Yes but the error you're getting is coming from code you're not showing. That makes it very hard for us to tell what is going on, because we don't have access to whatever "the team viewer" is...

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks Aaron for your time but this is the only code in my function and i have put the code completely here..... I don't know why it gave the error but still your comment down abt dropping the function helped me.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using style 100?

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FormatDate -- schema prefix always!
(
    @fromtime VARCHAR(50) -- varchar
)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS 
BEGIN -- don't need variables anywhere
   RETURN(CONVERT(DATETIME, @fromtime));
END
GO
```

Comment: i need those things later. That's why i'm using those variables

Comment: Later where? In the function?

Comment: yeah.. in the function.. stil have something else to do ..but in the middle got stuck with this error

Comment: So why not post the whole function, so we know the whole problem?

Comment: @user838359: There's something you're doing wrong then, because this code works fine for me.

Comment: I did not write the whole function. just going step wise.. this is what i wrote right now in the function.. and trying to run the select statement at the bottom

Comment: Then why don't you start at the beginning, e.g. drop the function mess for now and just try `SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '08/17/2010 4:30');` - does that work? Next try to figure out why you're using `m/d/y` instead of a safe format such as `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss`... you should never handle dates as strings, and if you have to, you should always handle them in a language- and regional settings-independent way.

Answer (score 2):

The 100 you're specifying in the convert is used to format when you're selecting data, not to format the storage of data.

Datetime is just stored as datetime - that's it (i mean, dependent on your SQL settings, it might be MM/DD/YYYY or DD/MM/YYYY).

But if you just do this:

```
set @tempfrom =  Convert(datetime, @fromtime)
```

it's now a datetime, which you can convert to your desired formatting by wrapping it in another convert:

```
convert(varchar, convert(datetime, @fromtime), 100)
```

Comment: Because that is to output a formatted string. You need to pick whether you want to output a formatted string or a datetime. Then the function needs to say RETURNS <that data type> and actually return <that data type>.